# Access request policy not being invoked in AuthZForce PDP

Tags: fiware, authz, pdp

Ive created this policy in the Domain of the AuthZForce PDP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<PolicySet
 xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"
 PolicySetId="P1"
 Version="1.0"
 PolicyCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:policy-combining-algorithm:deny-overrides">
 <Description>Reject if the Date is July PolicySet</Description>
 <Target />
 <Policy PolicyId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:date-in:july:policy" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:deny-overrides" Version="01">
<Description>Reject if the Date is July Policy</Description>
<Target />
<Rule RuleId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:date-in:july:rule" Effect="Deny">
<Condition>
    <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:any-of">
     <Function FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:date-is-in" />
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2017-07-01</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-02</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-03</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-04</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-05</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-06</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-07</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-08</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-09</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-10</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-11</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-12</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-13</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-14</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-15</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-16</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-17</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-18</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-19</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-20</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-21</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-22</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-23</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-24</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-25</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-26</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-27</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-28</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-29</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-30</AttributeValue>
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-31</AttributeValue>
<AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:date-in:july:current-date" 
    DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date" 
    MustBePresent="true"
    Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject"/>
</Apply>
</Condition>
</Rule>
</Policy>
</PolicySet>
```

and the response is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<link xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:ns2="http://authzforce.github.io/rest-api-model/xmlns/authz/5" xmlns:ns3="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" xmlns:ns4="http://authzforce.github.io/pap-dao-flat-file/xmlns/properties/3.6" xmlns:ns5="http://authzforce.github.io/core/xmlns/pdp/5.0" rel="item" href="P1/1.0" title="Policy 'P1' v1.0"/>
```

So I know that the policy is defined in the PDP.

However, when I run this request against the PDP domain, The policy is not evaluated, only the default allow-all:

```
<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"
 CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="true">
   <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
      <Attribute IncludeInResult="false"
                 AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:date-in:july:current-date">
         <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2017-07-01</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
   </Attributes>
</Request>
```

response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns3:Response xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:ns2="http://authzforce.github.io/rest-api-model/xmlns/authz/5" xmlns:ns3="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" xmlns:ns4="http://authzforce.github.io/pap-dao-flat-file/xmlns/properties/3.6" xmlns:ns5="http://authzforce.github.io/core/xmlns/pdp/5.0">
    <ns3:Result>
        <ns3:Decision>Permit</ns3:Decision>
        <ns3:PolicyIdentifierList>
            <ns3:PolicyIdReference Version="0.1.0">permit-all</ns3:PolicyIdReference>
            <ns3:PolicySetIdReference Version="0.1.0">root</ns3:PolicySetIdReference>
        </ns3:PolicyIdentifierList>
    </ns3:Result>
</ns3:Response>
```

why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to [question #15 on AuthzForce GitHub](https://github.com/authzforce/server/issues/15).
The PDP is still using policy with `PolicySetId = 'root'` as root policy, i.e. the policy where the PDP starts the evaluation. You can verify what the current root policy is (and related applicable policies used by it) at anytime, and change it if necessary, as told in the [doc](http://authzforce-ce-fiware.readthedocs.io/en/release-5.4.1e/UserAndProgrammersGuide.html#policy-decision-pdp-properties).

Only the root policy (specified by the PDP property `rootPolicyRefExpression`) or policies referenced by it (via `PolicySetIdReference`) are used actually by the PDP for evaluation. Therefore, if you want the PDP to evaluate your policy (`P1` in your case), either you change the `rootPolicyRefExpression` value to `P1` (the version is optional, the latest is used by default), or you can update the default policy `root` directly by re-uploading your policy with PolicySetId `root` instead of `P1`, and Version greater than the current version of policy `root` on the server.

Also your policy is not valid because date-is-in only takes 2 arguments, and the rule combining algorithm is deprecated and not supported by AuthzForce any longer. I understand you want to check whether your custom current-date is in a list of dates, here is a fixed version of the policy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<PolicySet xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"  PolicySetId="P1" Version="1.0" PolicyCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:policy-combining-algorithm:deny-overrides">
<Description>Reject if the Date is July PolicySet</Description>
<Target />
<Policy PolicyId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:date-in:july:policy" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:deny-overrides" Version="01">
  <Description>Reject if the Date is July Policy</Description>
  <Target />
  <Rule RuleId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:date-in:july:rule" Effect="Deny">
     <Condition>
        <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:date-is-in">
           <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:date-one-and-only">
              <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:date-in:july:current-date" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date" MustBePresent="true"
                 Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" />
           </Apply>
           <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:date-bag">
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2017-07-01</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-02</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-03</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-04</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-05</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-06</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-07</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-08</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-09</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-10</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-11</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-12</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-13</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-14</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-15</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-16</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-17</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-18</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-19</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-20</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-21</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-22</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-23</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-24</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-25</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-26</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-27</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-28</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-29</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-30</AttributeValue>
              <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2002-07-31</AttributeValue>
           </Apply>
        </Apply>
     </Condition>
  </Rule>
</Policy>
</PolicySet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but changing the rootPolicyRefExpression value to P1 resulted in an error of 
"Failed to find a root PolicySet with id = 'P1', Version=*,EarliestVersion=*,LatestVersion=*: Matched PolicySet 'P1' (version 1.1) is invalid or its content is unavailable" 
and updating the root policy set resulted in : 
"Failed to find a root PolicySet with id = 'root', Version=*,EarliestVersion=*,LatestVersion=*: Matched PolicySet 'root' (version 0.2.0) is invalid or its content is unavailable"

Comment: Maybe the policy is not valid. Can you check the AuthzForce server logs for more details? These would be in /var/log/tomcat8/authzforce-ce/error.log

Comment: I updated my answer with a valid version of the policy.

Comment: Thanks Cyril!
This did the trick, I was almost there as I discovered the date-bag function, but didn't realise I had to use the date-one-and-only function for the input variable.